# Semi-Transparent TextureViews not working

Tags: android, transparent, alpha, alpha-transparency, textureview

I cannot change the transparency of a TextureView by setAlpha method to maske it semi-transparent as it is promised by the android SDK. For example mTextureView.setAlpha(0.5f)
does not have any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I used to make it happen was to wrap the TextureView in another widget like RelativeLayout and change the transparency of the parent.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make sure and setOpaque(false).

From [the docs:](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)

> **public void setOpaque (boolean opaque) Added in API level 14**
>
> Indicates whether the content of this TextureView is opaque. The
>   content is assumed to be opaque by default.

Comment: Changing the content opacity seems to not have any effect when TextureView is used in video playback. I want to have a semi-transparent video playback using TextureView.

Comment: Works perfectly with OpenGL stuff.