# Camera2 preview is black, if I add a GLSurfaceView in front

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, z-order, textureview, camera2

I want to do an OpenGL animation (`GLSurfaceView`) in front of the Camera2 API preview (`TextureView`), but the animation isn't transparent. I've added the `GLSurfaceView` in front of the `TextureView`.

- it only works, if I set the `setZOrderOnTop(true);` in the `GLSurfaceView`, but then all buttons and also the drawer is behind of the the view...

Is there a way to make the the `GLSurfaceView` (animation) transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setZOrderOnTop()` works, but it means that you cannot have anything above a transparent `SurfaceView`, which is unfortunate.

The only way is, to replace the `TextureView` of the Camera2 preview, with a `SurfaceView`. Then I can use the `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);` in the `GLSurfaceView`.

> setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean isMediaOverlay)
>
> Control whether the surface view's surface is placed on top of another
>   regular surface view in the window (but still behind the window
>   itself).

Answer (score 2):

SurfaceView (and its sub-class GLSurfaceView) have two parts, the Surface and the View.  The Surface provides access to a separate layer, independent of the View UI layer.  You can position it in front of or behind the View layer, but it can't fit "between" Views.

Using `setZOrderOnTop(true)` is the correct way to place the Surface layer in front of the Views.  If that's not what you want, you should consider instead using a TextureView, as those are rendered on the View layer and can be positioned above or below individual Views.

You can render to a TextureView (or anything else with a Surface) with OpenGL ES.  See, for example, the "simple GL in TextureView" Activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Thx for your good answer!
I've used the TexturveView now, but the problem is that it isn't transparent. And also **setOpaque(false)** doesn't work...

Comment: `setOpaque(false)` is necessary (the system assumes opaque by default). Make sure you're clearing pixels with transparency, e.g. `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)` (note the explicit blend mode), or `glClear(0,0,0,0)`. Are you using `setAlpha()`? One answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993355/) found success by fiddling with the layout as well.

Comment: This is not possible with a TextureView. Even if you render a transparent clear color, it will be against a white background because of how Android uses texture views in its drawing system.